# use of $this cakephp subfunction

Tags: php, function, cakephp, this

I've done a search into stackoverflow but couldn't find anything.

Actually I'm working into recodding a "dirty" code done by a dev in a CakePHP 2.3 framework.

I'm not a dev myself, i'm more like a Swiss knife, i do some php but this is usually not my daily task.

:)

Let's go to the facts, i've got a controller with functions, and some functions under these functions...

Ex :

tool_controller.php

```
function addSomething(){

   print_r($this->loadModel("db")); //it works // returns 1

      function anotherFunction(){

         print_r($this->loadModel("db")); //returns "Using $this when not in object context"    

      }
}
```

I'm a bit lost, searched in CakePHP docs but couldn't find anything either.

Can someone please help ?

thanks

Comment: Why do you nest functions? It makes no sense in your example. Make  `anotherFunction` a method of the class or if you really want to do that, show full (non-working) example that shows the issue. Currently we don't know how these functions are invoked etc.

Comment: Why would one nest functions? functions should either be declared "next to" each other or as Methods in classes.

Comment: I did it this way because the first function is the result of a submit form, then there was the same code repeated many times by the old dev so i created a function with this code that I wanted to callback instead of repeating this code 10 times, everything works fine until I call the "loadModel" from CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After that many of you suggest me to not to nest functions, I've decided to follow your advice and I've putted outside my main function, after I call back my function.

```
Public Function loopAction(){

   //Code here

}

Public Function addsomething(){

   //Code here

   $this->loopAction();

}
```

It works perfectly and even better than before, thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

This code would most probably be better written like this:-

```
public function addSomething(){
    print_r($this->loadModel("db"));
    $this->_anotherFunction();    
}

protected function _anotherFunction(){
    print_r($this->loadModel("db"));
}
```

I doubt you really need to nest functions for what you want to achieve. The above code should be simpler to read and is more obvious what context `$this` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

OK people, i've solved my problem, as I told before the main function is an action after a submit, then I had a loop inside this function to treat the datas.

As i'm working in CakePHP and using the integrated functions (in this case the function "loadModel" in the "Controller" class), i had to get this function working in the nested function.

The solution was the following :

```
 function addSomething(){

   my_code_here

    function anotherFunction(){

       $controller = new Controller; // Had to redeclare the class

       print_r($controller->loadModel("db")); // Works just fine

  }
```

}

Thanks to all for your submissions.

Kind regards folks ;)

Comment: This is not really a good idea and isn't the CakePHP way of doing things. I highly doubt that you need to use nested PHP functions like this.

Comment: So you are telling me that you never nest functions?

Comment: Other than using closures I have never used nested functions as there is no need for them in PHP when writing object oriented code (like CakePHP).

Comment: Well, let say that you have a form page that when submitting it calls in the controller the function addSomething(), when treating the datas in the function addSomething() you have to make some loop to check a data in the database and this loop has to be made many times, instead of repeating the code the best way should be making a function for me or I should make outside the mail function and call it when needed?